# vertical alignment in a row

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a one-row table with a number of columns.
Each cell in this row is another table, which can be either 2x1 or 3x1.
I want to make sure that all these sub-tables are aligned to the top of the main row.
e.g.:

```
-------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
|  a  |  b  |  c  |
|  A  |     |  C  |
-------------------
```

A simple enough solution would be to add a phantom line to middle cell.
However, if all the cells are 2x1 I don't want to have an empty row:

```
-------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
|  a  |  b  |  c  |
|     |     |     |
-------------------
```

The above is not good for me, and should be

```
-------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
|  a  |  b  |  c  |
-------------------
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use

```
\begin{tabular}[t]
```

for the inner tables so they line up on their top row.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `[t]`-alignment for your nested `tabular`, wrapped in a macro to avoid inserting forced line breaks:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\vtable}[2][c]{% \vtable[<col align>]{<stuff>}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \vtable{1 \\ a \\ A} & \vtable{2 \\ b} & \vtable{3 \\ c \\ C}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \vtable{1 \\ a } & \vtable{2 \\ b} & \vtable{3 \\ c}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The definition of `\vtable` takes an optional argument that specifies the alignment within the nested `tabular`. The default here is `c`entred (as indicated by `[c]` in `\newcommand{\vtable}[2][c]`). So, `\vtable{...}` defaults to `\vtable[c]{...}`, which `c`entres the nested `tabular`. Using `\vtable[l]{...}` would impose a `l`eft-alignment within the nested `tabular`.

The second arguments takes the regular `tabular` definition for cells/rows, which could include `\\`. Using a nested `tabular` column specification of `@{}.@{}` removes the default padding around the column - LaTeX inserts `\tabcolsep` on either side of a column, unless otherwise specified. Using `@{}` removes this. As a reference, see [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764).

The [`makecell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) provides something similar through `\makecell`.

Comment: two questions:
(1) what is the purpose of [c] in the definition of vtable.
(2) what are the '@{}' parts for?

Comment: @giladrv: I've added some discussion in that regard. Let me know if you need more...

Comment: If I understand correctly, LaTeX pads a table with spaces, and we don't want more space for inner tables so that's what @{} is for?

Comment: regardless, the main question was answered here, thanks!

Comment: @giladrv: Yes. Your outer `tabular` adds the spaces already. So, if your inner `tabular` just used `c` (instead of `@{}c@{}`), it would double the space.